# Parsing text with different delimiters - with grouping

Tags: ruby, parsing, text

I am editing my earlier post because I have made some progress but am now a little stuck:

The text file example is below.  I can now read the file do some parsing to get at the data I need and output the file.  However, the output puts the data on separate lines and I need the output file to put (name, expiry date, last_used, address1, address2, city, state, zip) on one line separated by commas.

Here is the code thus far:

```
def is_numeric?(object)
true if Float(object) rescue false
end



def load_file
raw_records = []
infile = File.open("testfile.txt", "r") 
#counter =1 

while line = infile.gets
possible_account_number = line[0,16]
if is_numeric?(possible_account_number)
  account_number= possible_account_number[5,11]
  name = line[21,27].strip.gsub(/\,/,"")
  expire_date = line[108,8].strip
  last_used = line[117,8].strip    
  line = infile.gets
  line = infile.gets
  address1 = line.strip.gsub(/\,/,"") #needed for some random commas
  line = infile.gets
  address2 = line.strip.gsub(/\,/,"")
  line = infile.gets
  city = line[21, 20].strip.gsub(/\,/,"")
  state = line[42, 2]
  zip = line[45, 5]
  record = [name, expire_date,last_used, address1, address2, city, state, zip]
  raw_records << record
  #counter = counter + 1
 end

end
infile.close
puts raw_records.map {|record| record*','}

File.open('test_w.txt', 'w') do |f2|   
f2.puts raw_records.map {|record| record*','} 
end


end

#the_string.gsub(/\,/,"")


load_file
```

Here is the raw data:

```
11111 ABC MOVINGABC, INC                   1234567891 LISTINGS                 02-06-12  MONDAY             2112-001-001  PAGE     1
      1234 CUSTOMIA ROAD  SUITE 12345      LIST MANAGEMENT
      NOSAOLOS        NV 12345


STATEMENTS TISSUE    STATEMENTS NAME 1                 ABC        TISSUES       TISSUE ROAD        LOC      TISSUES  PAGE ABC TISSUE
                     STATEMENTS NAME 2
                     ADDRESS LINE 1
                     ADDRESS LINE 2
                     CITY                 ST ZIP

TITLE   TISSUE NUMBER: 123456789

1234567890000030     MARILYN SMITH                  12345678911                                             05-30-12 01-28-12

                     1234 ST MARYS BLVD.
                     SUITE B
                     NOSAOLOS             MI 12345

1234567890000048     MARILYN ACTIVITA               12345678911                                             05-30-12 09-04-11

                     1234 ST MARYS BOULEVARD
                     STE. B
                     NOSAOLOS             OH 12345

1234567890000055     ANDREW WAYMENT                 12345678911                                             05-30-12 01-12-12

                     123 S. DESCRIBE ST.

                     NOSAOLOS             OH 12345
```

Here is the finished text- with help from Jason (thanks):

```
MARILYN SMITH,5-30-12 ,1-28-12,1234 ST MARYS BLVD.,SUITE B,NOSAOLOS,MI,12345
MARILYN ACTIVITA,5-30-12 ,9-04-11,1234 ST MARYS BOULEVARD,STE. B,NOSAOLOS,OH,12345
ANDREW WAYMENT,5-30-12 ,1-12-12,123 S. DESCRIBE ST.,,NOSAOLOS,OH,12345
```

I also wanted it save to a file and I used this:

```
File.open('test_w.txt', 'w') do |f2|   
f2.puts raw_records.map {|record| record*','} 
end
```

Andrew

Comment: It would help a lot to NOT use a picture of the data. Providing us with a usable sample of the data helps us help you. Seeing the data helps a little, but I'm not about to type in the entire image's worth.

Comment: I would be happy to post the file but I do not see the option to include a file in the question.   Sorry I am new at this.

Comment: Do not post the entire file, just include a enough of a sample of the text so we can get the gist of the format. Insert it by editing your question and pasting it in. Either wrap the sample with `<pre>...</pre>` tags, or indent it four spaces. As an alternate, post the data to gist.com and include the link in your question.

Comment: Tin Man - here is a part of the file.  Thanks for you suggestion. I have been ill so I have not had a chance to post.   Any help would appreciated.

Comment: puts raw_records, when raw_records is an Array of Arrays will print each element on a different line. If you want all elements of the subarrays to be comma delimited, use: puts raw_records.map {|record| record*','}

Comment: Jason - thank you so much.  I am almost there. I am going to edit the post with this included any additional help will be much appreciated...

Comment: last_used still has an EOL character in it. You may want to do last_used = line[118,8].strip

Comment: jason - thank you again.  If there was a tip jar on this thing I would throw some cash your way... Thanks again.   I have posted my completed solution - I also had to use .gsub(/\,/,"") on most of the columns because deep in the file there were "," popping up everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to give you any code as an example without an input file, but the image of the file looks fairly predictable so a state tracker with some RegExp magic should do the trick.

The file looks tab delimited so you could split the lines by tab:

```
File.open('filename', 'r') do |file|
  lines = file.inject([]){|memo, line| memo.push line.split(/\t/)}
  # Now you have an array of arrays that you can parse with a state tracker
end
```

Your state tracker would simply track what you entered last such as number, name, or date_issued, and then populate the proper values.

Comment: The file looks like the output of a database report, which may not have tabs at all, especially if it came from a mainframe or legacy system.